# How to parse and remove fields from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-files

Source Data::

```
ads_data = [{
    "account_id": "12345",
    "display": [
        {
            "action_type": "video_view",
            "value": "123",
            "content": [{"type" : "Adult", "subject" : " Geography "}]
        }
        ],
    "display 1": [
        {
            "action_type": "video_view",
            "value": "321"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want the data like,

```
account_id|display|display_content_type|display_content_subject|display1
12345|123|Adult|Geography|321
```

As a novice I have tried various way playing on internet, but I could not. I am expecting you help in this and your help will be much appreciated.

```
df = []
for data in ads_data:
    keys = "|".join(data.keys())
print(keys)
for row in ads_data:
    for value in row.values():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for i in value:
                if isinstance(i, dict):
                    df.append(",".join(i.values()))
        else:
            df.append("|".join([str(value)]))
print(df)
```

Comment: I could not able to achieve the header like - account_id|display|display_content_type|display_content_subject|display1

And the value like 12345|123|Adult|Geography|321

Comment: Here, I know data is having three nested layers, suppose it will come more than that then how to resolve by the same code. That is also I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header is a subset of the keys in the nested dictionary so you'll need to define what that subset of keys is.  You can use that definition to associate header labels to each key path:

Assuming the lists inside your structure only ever have one item, you could approach it like this:

```
keyheaders = {("account_id",)                     : "account_id",
              ("display",0,"value")               : "display",
              ("display",0,"content",0,"type")    : "display_content_type",
              ("display",0,"content",0,"subject") : "display_content_subject",
              ("display 1",0,"value")             : "display1" }

data = ["|".join(keyheaders.values())]
for row in ads_data:
    values = []                   # list of values for row
    for keyPath in keyheaders:
        value = row
        for key in keyPath:       # drill down keys and indexes
            try:    value = value[key]
            except: value = ""
        values.append(value.strip())
    data.append("|".join(values)) # assemble values into data line

print(*data,sep="\n")

account_id|display|display_content_type|display_content_subject|display1
12345|123|Adult|Geography|321
```

If the nested lists in this structure can have more than one item, you would have to describe how you want the multiple items to be output.  (i.e. only the first one, multiply the lines repeating the other non-list values, ...)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But here how can I make keyheaders = {("account_id",)                     : "account_id",
              ("display",0,"value")               : "display",
              ("display",0,"content",0,"type")    : "display_content_type",
              ("display",0,"content",0,"subject") : "display_content_subject",
              ("display 1",0,"value")             : "display1" }
as dynamic.

Comment: keyheaders contains a selection of the keys that imply a decision or rule.  In order to build it dynamically, you need to provide some criteria and an example in your question.  Eventually you should place the code in a function that will take ads_data and keyheaders as parameter and return data. The dynamic construction of keyheaders would typically be a separate process or function.

Comment: Hi @Alain T, 
I have figure it out how to make keyheaders as dynamic based on my requirement.
I am getting error while processing million rows at a time using the same code. Throwing "list index out of range". So how I will fix it.

Comment: It is likely that your source data has at least one instance of a dictionary with an empty list as value.  You can make the code more robust using a try/except block.  I will add one in my example to illustrate.